# ADB doesn't see my Android device

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to get a generic Android device listed in adb in an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VMware guest OS. The device is running Android 4.0.4 and gets listed in the Windows 10 host OS, but once I switch it to the guest OS, I don't see it. I see it in lsusb though. I've tried including it in 51-android.rules but still no go.

Answer (score -1):

First, just try adb kill-server and adb devices. If no use, make sure you have done all the following steps(for example add 0x2357 device):

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:9091 Qualcomm, Inc.
```

sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/51-Android.rules

```
# Qualcomm: u10, u20
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2357",, MODE="0600", OWNER="login_name"
```

sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/51-Android.rules

echo 0x2357 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

adb kill-server && adb devices